# Notepad++ any character any length

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++ how do I use find, to match anything, so that this search will work?

```
User [ANYTHING.ANY.LENGTH.ANY.CHARACTER] from [
```

This is some extra random text, because this website wont let me post without it, for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

`.*` will match anything except linebreak with length from 0 upto infinite.

If you want to match a line that have text inside square brackets, use:

```
^.*\[.*?\].*$
```

If you want to also match linebreak, use: `(?s).*` or `^(?s).*\[.*?\].*$`.

Comment: Inserting that into the above as such:

User [.*] from [

Returns invalid regular expression I'm afraid.

Comment: You need to escape the square brackets as they are special characters in a regex - `\[.*\]`

Comment: @extremelyfrustratednotepaduser: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1742800/edit) and add sample lines and expected result.